# CSS - cross browser compatibility = different style sheets?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am in the process of learning CSS while designing a simple commenting system.
I use firefox(4.0beta13pre if anyone cares) as my main browser so I do all testing with it.

after making a small piece look perfectly with It, I found out an image wasn't aligned in chrome, and than opening Internet Explorer it looked like complete garbage.

So is it just a matter of trying harder to achieve compatibility or is it that even a simple system needs different style sheets to other browsers?

Thanks,
Fingerman.

Comment: For a simple thing like that, you'll be able to get it right with just one stylesheet. It just takes some fiddling around. Would you mind posting some code, and we might be able to help?

Comment: I find the best resources for debugging cross-browser style issues to be [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) and [firebug-lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it just a matter of trying harder to achieve compatibility

Partially, that's the case.

For a better starting point, look at [CSS reset files](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=reset+CSS). These ensure that you are starting from a (more or less) level playing field on all browsers, so achieving compatibility is easier.

You may also need to put in specific browser "hacks" and overrides, but this really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Oded, you *never* need to put in specific browser hacks. Unless you count conditional comments for IE, and vendor-specific styles (i.e. -moz-border-radius, -webkit-border-radius,...) as "hacks" (which they are not).

Comment: @Oded, then you shouldn't be using a "hack"; you should be using `<!--[if IE 6]>add IE 6 stylesheet here<![endif]-->` to add an IE specific stylesheet. At this point, I don't bother supporting IE6 any more unless an employer has a *very* good reason to need support.

Comment: @zzzzBov - fair enough, but the OP didn't specify a list of browsers he needs to support. And even conditional stylesheets are not always enough.

Comment: @Oded, I have never had a case where a conditional stylesheet was not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is generally a matter of trying harder to find a combination of HTML/CSS that works across browsers/versions. It's a major pain, but such is the life of a web developer.

I'd definitely try to tweak before creating separate style sheets for different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning CSS, i suggest you take a look at https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/tree/master/blueprint/src. It has ie.css which containes hacks pertaining to IE. It also contains reset.css. Intially, it will help you start. Later, you can make your customized css stylesheets.